# Excel - SUMIF Function

Tags: excel, sumifs

I made a worksheet covering meal expenses for a set period of time (01-08-2020 until 31-08-2020.)
The company will pay up to 75kr, Monday-Friday.
The list covers expenses 7 days a week, If the amount is greater than 75 on Monday-Friday, I have to pay the extra expenses. (This I have figured out correctly). Saturday and Sunday I have to pay fully.

So my question is, how can I sum this and exclude Saturday and Sunday?

**Attempt 1:**
I tried this formula (Norwegian excel. Summerhvis = SUMIF. Lørdag = Saturday):
**=SUMMERHVIS(B2:B32,"<>lørdag", G2:G32)**

It seems to be partly correct however, I miss Sunday, how can I add Sunday to this equation?

**Attempt 2:**
I used this formula:
**=SUMMERHVIS(B2:B32,B2:B6,G2:G32)**

It gave the correct answer but the answer was layered in 5 rows. I then summed this in P8.
Where I want the answer is in G32. So in G32 I wrote =p8.

It must be an easier way of doing this?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Am I understanding you correctly if I assume your original table only contains columns A:F, and you want to know the total the employer will contribute using as few helper columns as possible?

Comment: Would a [weekday function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/weekday-function-60e44483-2ed1-439f-8bd0-e404c190949a?ui=en-us&rs=en-us&ad=us) help you?  It returns a number and you might set a condition like "<6" make your sums.

Comment: @eirikdaude - The original columns are A:K.
I want to find out whats G2:G32 without adding Saturday (lørdag) and Sunday(søndag).
I want the answer in G33.

Regarding A:F is my "attempt 2".

Comment: @EvilBlueMonkey - Hmm, yeah that might work but still unsure how I would get that into my equation as in the comment above?

Comment: `=WEEKDAY(A2,2)` in cell L2 (dragged down) and `=SUMIF($L$2:$L$32,"<6",$G$2G$32)` should do the trick.

Comment: Welcome to SO. About posting original function names, please post them always in english. If you do not know the name in english, just google for excel function in your language, and you will find a link like https://support.microsoft.com/nb-no/office/summerhvis-funksjon-169b8c99-c05c-4483-a712-1697a653039b  Just replace `nb-no` with `en-us` and you will see the english version :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `SUMPRODUCT` and the `WEEKDAY` function:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((WEEKDAY(A2:A32,3)<5)*G2:G32)
```

According to the Microsoft function translator, this might be, in Norwegian:

```
=SUMMERPRODUKT((UKEDAG(A2:A32;3)<5)*G2:G32)
```

If you really want to use `SUMIF` and your text days, one way would be (in English):

```
=SUM(SUMIF(B2:B32,{"Monday";"Tuesday";"Wednesday";"Thursday";"Friday"},G2:G32)),
```

or, if your weekday days are in b4:b8:

```
=SUM(SUMIF(B2:B32,$B$4:$B$8,G2:G32))
```

but I'd advise against it as it would only work in the language of the text days of the week.  Also, I note your days of the week don't seem to match up with what the days of the week were in the US.  For example, here `1 Aug 2020` was a `Saturday`, so another possible cause for error (unless I am not understanding the dates correctly).

The above is the same as summing five separate `SUMIF` equations, each for a desired day of the week.